# Convert Rest API JSON Response into C# object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a code REST API response which is json, and parsing to JObject and pulling a value from it. But i am getting the error when parsing to JObject.

Error: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Is there any other way to convert Json string to C# object.

I have the following code:
        using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
    using (HttpResponseMessage message = httpclient.GetAsync(folderIdURL).Result)
    {
        if(message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var dataobjects = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //dataobjects = "{"id":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/","title":"DQL query results","author":[{"name":"EMC Documentum"}],"updated":"2019-05-02T15:19:52.508+00:00","page":1,"items-per-page":100,"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/?dql=SELECT%20r_object_id%2cobject_name%20FROM%20dm_sysobject%20WHERE%20FOLDER%20(%27%2fgbc%2fUS%2fOSA-ATTACHMENT%2f2019%27)"}],"entries":[{"id":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/?dql=SELECT%20r_object_id%2cobject_name%20FROM%20dm_sysobject%20WHERE%20FOLDER%20(%27%2fgbc%2fUS%2fOSA-ATTACHMENT%2f2019%27)&index=0","title":"0b0111738011c114","updated":"2019-05-02T15:19:52.508+00:00","published":"2019-05-02T15:19:52.508+00:00","links":[{"rel":"edit","href":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/objects/0b0111738011c114"}],"content":{"json-root":"query-result","definition":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositori                      es/dmgbsap_crt/types/dm_sysobject","properties":{"r_object_id":"0b0111738011c114","object_name":"04"},"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/objects/0b0111738011c114"}]}},{"id":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/?dql=SELECT%20r_object_id%2cobject_name%20FROM%20dm_sysobject%20WHERE%20FOLDER%20(%27%2fgbc%2fUS%2fOSA-ATTACHMENT%2f2019%27)&index=1","title":"0b0111738011c115","updated":"2019-05-02T15:19:52.509+00:00","published":"2019-05-02T15:19:52.509+00:00","links":[{"rel":"edit","href":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/objects/0b0111738011c115"}],"content":{"json-root":"query-result","definition":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/types/dm_sysobject","properties":{"r_object_id":"0b0111738011c115","object_name":"05"},"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://gbc-dev5.cloud.wc.com/DctmRest/repositories/dmgbsap_crt/objects/0b0111738011c115"}]}}]}"

            JObject responseObj = JObject.Parse(dataobjects.ToString());
            String id = (String)responseObj["entries" -->"content"-->"properties"-->"object_name"];
        }                                      

    }
```

}

I am expecting the value from (String)responseObject["enteries"]["content"][" properties"]["object_name"]

Comment: `entries` is an array, and in the example you give (in the comment) has two values. That array would not have a `content` properties.

Answer (score 7):

JObjects are a pain. You could get a sample of the JSON response and paste it into a converter like json2csharp.com. It will generate a class for you which you can then use like so:

Generated Class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
     Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.SomeProperty);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I never know there is JSON to C# converter tool. This is awesome. let me validate :)

Comment: the classes created from tool, the class names and properties should match with exact name with JSON string elements?

Comment: @AdithyaM Correct.

Comment: I used the same exact class names which were generated from json2csharp.com and used the starting class. the JSON converted into Objects, i am able to get the required value from JSON. You made my day easy. I'm struggling this from last 2 days. Thank you So much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to follow those steps:

1. You need to check that your `json` is actually a `json`, because an error says it is not. You can use online [tools like this](http://jsonlint.com)
2. If possible, avoid JObject and generate real classes. It is not that hard if you know the structure, and you can use [another online tools](http://json2csharp.com)
3. Modify your code to use classes

so you will have something like:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Message
        {
            public Enteries enteries { get; set; }
        }
        public class Enteries
        {
            public Content content { get; set; }
        }
        public class Content
        {
            public Properties properties { get; set; }
        }
        public class Properties
        {
            public string object_name { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "{\"enteries\":{\"content\":{ \"properties\":{ \"object_name\":\"your value string\"}}}}";
            Message msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(input);
            Console.WriteLine(msg?.enteries?.content?.properties?.object_name ?? "no value");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I will check and let you know asap :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft.Json

First get the list of entries from the `responseObj`. Then loop each entries and use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) to get values by property name or index.

You can use  `Item[Object]` index on JObject/JArray and then cast the returned JValue to the type you want

```
JObject responseObj = JObject.Parse(dataobjects.ToString());

// get JSON result objects into a list
IList<JToken> entries = responseObj ["entries"].Children().ToList();

foreach(JToken entry in entries)
{
    string object_name = (string) entry["content"]["properties"]["object_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all the help and trips. Finally i am able to get the required value from JSON string.

Here is the Final code json2csharp.com

```
public class Author
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Link2
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string r_object_id { get; set; }
    public string object_name { get; set; }
}

public class Link3
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string json_root { get; set; }
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
    public List<Link3> links { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    public DateTime published { get; set; }
    public List<Link2> links { get; set; }
    public Content content { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Author> author { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int items_per_page { get; set; }
    public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
}
```